# If I compile Visual Studio Code from source, is the compiled version licensed from MIT or Microsoft's license?

Tags: mit, microsoft

I intend to compile Visual Studio Code on my own to be able to redistribute it.
But I still don't know whether I could do that.
So may I know if the compiled version uses the MIT License or Microsoft's license which prohibits redistribution?

Comment: Closely related (but I think not quite a duplicate): [Is Microsoft VS code really open source?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4288/50)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in [issue #60](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60#issuecomment-161792005) in the vscode github repository.

In short, the vscode sources are available under the MIT license, but the Microsoft-branded binaries are distributed under the more restrictive Microsoft license.